# Repeat random sampling of rows

Tags: r, subset, sampling

I have a dataframe containing 2 columns: column 1 are ID's and column 2 are values associated with each ID (totalling 59 different rows).

Example:

```
     [ID] [value] 
[1]   a   164  
[2]   b   167  
[3]   c   120  
[4]   d   117  
[5]   e   106
```

I am assuming that the only way I can randomly sample from column 1 and keep the associated value in column 2, is by sampling rows. I need to randomly sample  50 x 1 row, 50 x 2 rows, 50 x 3 rows, 50 x 4 rows etc. up to 59 rows. Ideally, with each sample set output as a dataframe. So, I would end up with 59 sets of randomly sampled data. Essentially this is the same as creating random subsets of data.

I have this code which produces a df of 10 randomly sampled rows for example.

```
sample_df<-df[sample.int(nrow(df),size=10,replace=TRUE),]
```

The question is how can I adjust this code so that it produces 50 times 10 random rows? Should I be using a loop to generate all of the random samples that I need?

Comment: This is a question about `R` and not on topic here. Try `example <- data.frame(a = LETTERS, b= letters, c= 1:26); lapply(as.list(1:50), function(x) example[sample(1:26, size =  10, replace=TRUE),])` for a list of 50 samples or ask on stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, use a loop. Or one of R's shortcuts for loops, like `sapply`, `lapply`, or `replicate`. `replicate` is good if you want to repeat the exact same code, i.e., the problem as described in your last paragraph, "*how can I adjust this code so that it produces 50 times 10 random rows?*". `sapply` would be good if you want different numbers of samples each time, as seems to be the case in your first paragraph. I can't tell which of those you are really after...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `lapply`, which will return a list of data frames:

`lapply(1:59, function(x) df[sample(nrow(df), size = x, replace = TRUE),])`